Remove part of path in proxy_pass
I need to get rid of squirrelmail/ part from path that's user see.
My .conf:
location / {
    rewrite /squirrelmail/(.*) /$1 last;
    proxy_pass https://internal.domain.tld:8081/squirrelmail/;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}


I expect that's my app available for users at root path /, instead of constantly adding squirrelmail/ to end user path.
So when user goes to https://mail.domain.tld it properly proxy pass actual app located at https://internal.domain.tld:8081/squirrelmail/ without adding squirrelmail/ to users path (e.g. https://mail.domain.tld/squirrelmail/)
UPD:
Without rewrite, after user goes to https://mail.domain.tld it adds squirrelmail/ part to the following requests (like navigate to another tab, open mail and etc.) by application, so for user it now look like https://mail.domain.tld/squirrelmail/?some=params but for application it now https://internal.domain.tld:8081/squirrelmail/squirrelmail/?some=params which cause HTTP 404.

You need to check Squirrelmail settings to set the root path of the application.

@TeroKilkanen it's not actually Squirrelmail, it's Roundcube, and the app itself isn't responsible for adding the squirrelmail/ path, it's hosted on another nginx that handles this app at internal.domain.tld:8081/squirrelmail, it also contains other programs (e.g. phpmyadmin, etc.), so each program is located in its own path (e.g. /squirrelmail, /phpmyadmin, etc.). So I can't just assign this app to the root path. I need to correctly proxy_pass the roundcube application from internal.domain.tld:8081/squirrelmail to mail.domain.tld.

You can have internal.example.com:8001/squirrelmail as the path internally. But in Roundcube settings, you need to set the root URL to mail.example.com. Then Roundcube will generate proper URLs for the users.

@TeroKilkanen As I mentioned above, roundcube has nothing to do with adding squirrelmail/ to the path, it doesn't even have a setting to set the base path.

it doesn't even have a setting to set the base path - and what is this? Can you try to add proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Path '/'; to your nginx config?

And in general, as @TeroKilkanen already said, each application need to be tuned separately. For phpmyadmin, check this link.

@IvanShatsky adding `X-Forwarded-Path' didn't help
